# Is it possible angular velocity of reaction wheels become 100 deg/s or not?

Tags: reaction-wheel

Is it possible angular velocity of reaction wheels become 100 deg/s or not? I simulate the satellite with two reaction wheels, and I get the below figure for the angular velocity of the reaction wheels:
[image]

Comment: This really seems like a limitation of the chart you've chosen to use to show the reaction wheel angular velocities, rather than any limitation on your simulated reaction wheels.

Comment: How fast a reaction wheel can spin depends on how it was made.  There are some out there capable of 6000 rpm, which is 100 *complete revolutions* in one second.

Comment: The question seems to suggest that you have a reason to suspect that the angular velocity of a reaction wheel **cannot** be 100 deg/s.  If so, then why do you think that?

Comment: $100°$ / s is only $16\frac23$ RPM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100 deg/s is rather slow. [This wheel](https://www.cubesatshop.com/product/cubewheel-small/) is rated for 8000 rpm, 48000 deg/s. Bigger wheels tend to be a bit slower, but not a lot slower.